# Not able to transact with paypal future payments

Tags: android, node.js, paypal, nodes, payment-gateway

I am using Android and Node JS for paypal integration for automatic payment from one account to another.(Future Payment)

I have got access to paypal account from buyer and passed the `Authorization Code` and `MetaData Id` from my android app onto my node server.

I have fetched `refresh token` and `access token` from the Authorization Code and created a future payment and capture the payment using following code:

```
var future_payment_config = {
    "PayPal-Client-Metadata-Id": metaId,
    "Authorization": refresh_token
};
//Set up payment details
var create_payment_json = {
    "intent": "authorize",
    "payer": {
        "payment_method": "paypal"
    },
    "transactions": [{
        "amount": {
            "currency": "USD",
            "total": "1.88"
        },
        "description": "future of sauces"
    }]
};

var pay_id = "";

var url = "";

//Create future payment
paypal.payment.create(create_payment_json, future_payment_config, function(error, payment) {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error.response);
        throw error;
    } else {
        console.log("Authorization Object : " + JSON.stringify(payment));
        pay_id = payment.id;
        for (var index = 0; index < payment.transactions[0].related_resources[0].authorization.links.length; index++) {
            //Redirect user to this endpoint for redirect url
            if (payment.transactions[0].related_resources[0].authorization.links[index].rel === 'capture') {
                // console.log(payment.links[index].href);
                url = payment.transactions[0].related_resources[0].authorization.links[index].href;

                var execute_payment_json = { "amount": { "currency": "USD", "total": "1.50" }, "is_final_capture": true }

                var payer_id = payment.payer.payer_info.payer_id;
                // var paymentId = { "paymentId" : pay_id};

                // paymentId = {
                //     "PayPal-Client-Metadata-Id": metaId,
                //     "Authorization": refresh_token
                // };
                // console.log(execute_payment_json, paymentId);

                paypal.authorization.capture(payment.transactions[0].related_resources[0].authorization.id, execute_payment_json, function(error, payment) {
                    if (error) {
                        console.log(error.response);
                        throw error;
                    } else {
                        console.log("Get Payment Response");
                        console.log(JSON.stringify(payment));
                    }
                });

            }
        }
    }
});
```

I am not able to do transaction. I want to know, if I need to do something more for transaction. I have also tried to use `paypal.execute` (shown below) :

```
function executePayment(paymentId, payerId) {
    var details = {
        "payer_id": payerId,
        "transactions": [{
            "amount": {
                "currency": "USD",
                "total": "1.88"
            },
            "description": "future of sauces"
        }]
    };
    paypal.payment.execute(paymentId, details, function(error, payment) {
        if (error) {
            console.log("Error :", error);
        } else {
            console.log("Result : ",payment);
        }
    })
}
```

The error I am getting on `paypal.execute` is this:

```
Error : { [Error: Response Status : 400]
  response: 
   { name: 'INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR',
     message: 'An internal service error has occurred',
     information_link: 'https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR',
     debug_id: 'a544d3865cd51',
     httpStatusCode: 400 }
```

I want to know, if I am on the right track! I want the Buyer to subscribe to future payments and the Facilitator will deduct the payment automatically.

Thanks in Advance.